# Please recommend an interpreted language with pattern matching

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, scripting-language, interpreted-language

I'm looking for an interpreted language that's easy for quick scripting like [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) but has more of a Haskell feel to it (i.e. a functional language).

Specifically, I want it to have pattern matching features like in haskell. Does such a thing exist?

EDIT: I mainly ask because I like learning new languages and I noticed there was an empty spot  in the languages I've been learning.
On the one hand I had interpreted and dynamically typed languages like Python and Ruby that had functional elements, but didn't take the concept too far.
On the other hand I had Haskell which has many of the functional features I enjoy but is very strict (it takes me a fair amount of time to get even simple programs to work).
I was just wondering if there is something that splits these differences.

Comment: Haskell is easy for quick scripting....

Comment: Racket offers pattern matching, is functional, and "impure" as scripting languages are. Whether it is "easy" or not is very subjective IMHO, like any other language.

Comment: Try HUGS, it's a Haskell implementation.

Comment: Why do you want an interpreter?

Comment: I've found Ruby enough of *functional feel*. There is a nice gem called [contracts](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby) which draws programming nearer to haskell and can help catch many errors at design time. I'm curious why are you asking particular for pattern matching, what do you expect from this.

Comment: F# has a REPL mode with F Sharp Interactive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd233175.aspx and supports pattern matching.

Comment: @chi racket looks very interesting, great suggestion.

Comment: @DonStewart good question... to be honest I'm not really sure. I'll edit to clarify my thoughts.

Comment: @DavidUnric I just enjoy pattern matching as a feature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Haskell

You can use `runhaskell` to execute a haskell file. The file is run immediately like a python script.

```
runhaskell test.hs
```

Prints `Hello Wolrd!`

If test.hs contains

```
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

### Scala

Another language that is less pure would be Scala. It targets the JVM and can therefore use all Java Libraries. You can use it as a script with:

```
scala test.scala
```

Where test.scala is just:

```
println("Hello, World!")
```

For pattern matching there is match case:

```
def headSafe[A](arg: List[A]):Option[A] = arg match {
  case x::xs => Some(x)
  case _     => None
}
```

`Option` corresponds to Haskells `Maybe` monand.
If you are interested in scala you can have a look at http://scala-lang.org

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out Scala.